# Are the two complexities O((2n + 1)!) and O(n!) equal?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

This may be a naive question but I am new to the concept of Big-O notation and complexity and could not found any answer for this. I am dealing with a problem for which the algorithm (2n + 1)! times check a condition. Can I say that the complexity of the problem is O(n!) or the complexity is O((2n + 1)!)?

Comment: This is a homework question isn't it?

Comment: No, it is part of my thesis work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation):

```
n! ~ (n / e)^n * sqrt(2 * pi * n)
```

Then

```
(2n + 1)! ~ ((2n + 1) / e)^(2n + 1) * sqrt(2 * pi * (2n + 1))
          >= (2n / e)^(2n) * sqrt(2 * pi * 2n)
          = 2^2n * (n / e)^(2n) * sqrt(2) * sqrt(2 * pi * n)
          = sqrt(2) * (2^n)^2 * ((n / e)^n)^2 * sqrt(2 * pi * n)
```

And now it's pretty clear why there's no hope of `O((2n + 1)!)` being `O(n!)`: the exponential factors are way worse. It's more like `O((2n + 1)!)` is `O((n!)^2)`.

Comment: Oh, [LaTeX on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow/60020#60020), how I long for thee.

Comment: So, we can not even say O((2n + 1)!) = O((2n)!). Am I correct?

Comment: Correct. `O((2n + 1)!)` would be `O(n * (2n)!)`.

Comment: You can always use an online site that will generate an image ([example](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)) for you to put here, albeit a bit more effort.

Answer (score 3):

Let (N,c) be any ordered pair of positive constants. Let n be any integer such that n>N and n>c.

Then (2n+1)! > (2n+1)*n! > cn!

Thus for any pair of positive constants (N,c) there exists n>N such that (2n+1)! > cn!, so (2n+1)! is not O(n!).

O((2n+1)!) contains a function, (2n+1)!, that is not in O(n!), so O((2n+1)!) and O(n!) are not the same.

(I concur in wanting LaTeX.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation . So we need to check whether there exists a constant c, and n0 such that:

```
(2n+1)! < cn! for n > n0
```

Intuitively, from observing how (2n+1)! and n! behave:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n!+%3E%282n+%2B1%29!

(2n+1)! just goes two times faster, so regardless of "c" it will always reach n!. So you can't simplify to n!.

Comment: You need to look at (2n+1)!/n!.  Just comparing like this would lead one to believe that n=o(3n).

Comment: Well, but indeed O(3n) = O(n).

Comment: I agree, but if I change your method to examine http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3n+%3E+n , I might be led to conclude otherwise.

Comment: It's "intuitive" in this situation, as I've said. In your example, you just need to apply constant c=3 to see that it's the same. In the above example using constant c=2 leads to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2n!+%3E+%282n%2B1%29! which still looks the same. But of course you are right that universally it's not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

> (2n+1)! = n!(n+1)...(2n+1)
>
> O((2n+1)!) = O(n!)O((n+1)...(2n+1))

==>

> O(1) = o((n+1)...(2n+1))
>
> O(n!) = o((2n+1)!)

Comment: @icepack with your justification one can conclude for example O(2n + 1) is greater than O(n), however as I know O(2n + 1) = O(n).

Comment: @Barpa No, it's not. It's little-o in the last 2 lines on the right side

Comment: `=` doesn't make sense in the last two lines.  You mean `⊂`.

Comment: @Teepeemm `=` is an accepted notation when describing complexities and is interchangeable with the standard set inclusion symbol

Comment: I agree that `=` is interchangeable with `∈` in practice.  This is accepted because (IMO) you can't confuse `n! ∈ o((2n+1)!)` with `o((2n+1)!) ∈ n!` (the first is correct, the second nonsensical).  But I haven't seen `=` replacing `⊂`.  As it stands, it seems easy to confuse `O(n!) ⊂ o((2n+1)!)` with `o((2n+1)!) ⊂ O(n!)` (the first is correct, the second incorrect).

Comment: @Teepeemm sorry, that doesn't sound convincing